# How is this combinatorial entity called?

Tags: combinatorics

How is this called:

$$\frac{3!}{2!} + \frac{3!}{1!} + \frac{3!}{0!} = 15$$

For example with `a`,`b`,`c` it would be:

`a`,`ab`,`ac`,`abc`,`acb`,

`b`,`ba`,`bc`,`bac`,`bca`,

`c`,`ca`,`cb`,`cab`,`cba`

Comment: I would call it "how many nonempty strings can be made from the letters $\{a,b,c\}$ without using any letter more than once".

Comment: Are you referring to _permutation_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be prepared to extend it to `3!/3! + 3!/2! + 3!/1! + 3!/0! = 16` to include the case where you have an empty ordered subset.

More generally for positive $n$ $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!} = \lfloor n! \times e \rfloor.$$

[OEIS A000522](https://oeis.org/A000522) and [A007526](https://oeis.org/A007526) suggest these are called "arrangements", but centuries ago were called "variations".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're referring to counting.

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{k!}$ tells you the number of nonempty tuples obtainable from a set of size $n$.